# Delphi - Encontrar e salvar Linhas de texto

Tags: delphi

Boa noite,

Tenho um arquivo de texto com varias linhas, onde as linhas que me interessam são as que começão com 'PU' e 'PD' onde dentro destas linhas existem valores que gostaria de atribuir a duas variáveis.

```
PW0.350,6;
PW0.350,7;
PW0.350,8;
LT;
SP1;
PU-3651 -2229;
PD-2851 -2229;
PD-2851 -1429;
PD-3651 -1429;
PD-3651 -2229;
SP0;
```

por exemplo a primeira linha que me interessa 'PU-3651 -2229'
gostaria de salvar o (-3651 na variável x e o -2229 na y)
alguém poderia me ajudar

OBS: ja estou abrindo o arquivo

```
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
      linhasarq := opendialog1.FileName;
      AssignFile(arquivo,opendialog1.FileName);
      Memo1.Text := opendialog1.FileName;
      reset(arquivo);
      while Not (Eof(arquivo)) do
      Begin
      ReadLn(arquivo,linhasarq);
      Memo2.Lines.Add(linhasarq);
      end;
      CloseFile(arquivo);
```

Comment: usei agora o comando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia Guilhermeths.. tudo certinho?? :)
Aparentemente é simples..
Uma das maneiras que poderia ser feito seria assim..:

```
Var
  Var_X,Var_Y,linhasarq : String;
begin
 if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
      linhasarq := opendialog1.FileName;
      AssignFile(arquivo,opendialog1.FileName);
      Memo1.Text := opendialog1.FileName;
      reset(arquivo);
      while Not (Eof(arquivo)) do
      Begin
      ReadLn(arquivo,linhasarq);
      If (Pos('PU-',linhasarq) > 0) then
         begin
           Var_X:= Copy(linhasarq,3,Pos(' ',linhasarq)-1);//PU-3651 -2229;  Copia da posicao 3 = -, Ate a posicao espaco.. Retornando -3651
           Var_Y:= Copy(linhasarq,Pos(' ',linhasarq)+1,Length(linhasarq) - 1);
         end
      Else
        If (Pos('PD-',linhasarq) > 0) then
           begin
             Var_X:= Copy(linhasarq,3,Pos(' ',linhasarq)-1);//PD-2851 -2229;  Copia da posicao 3 = -, Ate a posicao espaco.. Retornando -2851
             Var_Y:= Copy(linhasarq,Pos(' ',linhasarq)+1,Length(linhasarq) - 1);
           end;

      RichEdit1.Lines.Add(linhasarq+ ' - Var_X '+Var_X+' Var_Y '+Var_Y);
      end;
      CloseFile(arquivo);
    end; 

end;
```

Coloquei os valores na linha abaixo para serem visto por voce.. 
 **RichEdit1.Lines.Add(linhasarq+ ' - Var_X '+Var_X+' Var_Y '+Var_Y);**
Espero ter entendio seu problema e ter respondido claramente..
Qualquer coisa é só falar.. Abraços :)

paravra:= 'PU-3651 -2229;';

Uso do Pos(Substring,palavra) : Integer;
Var_T:= Pos('U',palavra); // = 3

Uso do COPY(palavra, de , ate).

Var_X:= Copy(palavra,4,Pos(' ',palavra)-1); 
Ele ira Retorna 3651 pois estamos pedindo o Quarto caracter ate o primeiro espaço menos um ( -1)

Comment: Está faltando um "else continue;" para os casos em que a linha não começar nem com PU nem com PD.

Comment: Ricardo, muito obrigado por esta explicação já me ajudou muito. Porem estou recebendo como valor na variável X '' -3651 - '' como faço para remover esse '' -'' e na variável Y esta aparecendo o ;  tentei usar stringreplace, porem não consegui

Comment: Bom dia Guilhermeths.. complementei o exemplo com a descrição do POS e do COPY..Acho que agora da para ti compreender melhor.. qualquer coisa é só falar :)

Answer (score 0):

Não sei qual versão do Delphi está utilizando, portanto considerei que seja as mais recentes (XE pra frente).

```
Uses
    System.RegularExpressions;

Var
  linhasarq, Valores: String;
  ValoresArray: TArray<string>;
  rgxSoNumero: TRegEx;

if OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin
    rgxSoNumero = TRegEx.Create('[a-zA-Z;]+');

    linhasarq := opendialog1.FileName;
    AssignFile(arquivo,opendialog1.FileName);
    Memo1.Text := opendialog1.FileName;
    reset(arquivo);
    while Not (Eof(arquivo)) do
    Begin
      ReadLn(arquivo,linhasarq);
      Memo2.Lines.Add(linhasarq);

      if (linhasarq.StartsWith('pu-'), true) or (linhasarq.StartsWith('pd-', true))
      begin
          Valores := rgxSoNumero.Replace(linhasarq, '').Trim; // Pega somente os números, sinal de menos e espaço da linha
          ValoresArray := Valores.Split([' ']);
          Memo2.Lines.Add('Valor X: '+ValoresArray[0]+' Valor Y: '+ValoresArray[1] );
      end;


    end;
    CloseFile(arquivo);
end;
```